# Having trouble creating a conditional template item in a AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm a Java/Python developer that was thrown onto an AngularJS project.

I was able to easily grasp most of the concepts but some of the syntax/functionality still eludes me.

I have this code that handles the login/logout functionality. If the user is logged in, it should show X. I'm trying to change it so that the offered template is conditional.

```
if loggedIn
   show this
else
   show this
```

I know that I have to use the template variable to set the generated HTML for the page. How would I go about creating that?

This is the code that I'm trying to change.

```
.directive('login', ['loginService', function(loginService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-show="session.loggedIn" class="loginwidget">Logged In: {{ session.username }} <button ng-click="session.logOut()">Log Out</button> </div>',
        //scope: { user: '=' },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.session = loginService.session();
        }
    };
}])
;
```

The project is in AngularJS v1.0.8. I'm planning to upgrade it when I can since the **ng-if** directive was introduced later and I think that'll solve some of the problems. I also wanna make sure that the project uses an up-to-date version of the AngularJS library.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this...

```
.directive('login', ['loginService', function(loginService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: 
            '<div> ' +
            '    <div ng-show="session.loggedIn" class="loginwidget"> ' +
            '        Logged In: {{ session.username }} <button ng-click="session.logOut()">Log Out</button> ' +
            '    </div>' +
            '    <div ng-show="!session.loggedIn" class="loginwidget"> ' +
            '        Logged Out <button ng-click="session.logIn()">Log In</button> ' +
            '    </div>' +
            '</div>',
        //scope: { user: '=' },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.session = loginService.session();
        }
    };
}])
;
```

Now the other part I believe you are missing is checking how scope.session will change when the user logs out.

This particular directive will bind to your parent controller and when scope.session on the parent changes, this controller will update as part of the digest cycle.  Do you have code in the parent to change the session when the user signs in/out?

Comment: Yea theres code to check/handle the session in the parent. I'll give this a shot real quick.